# Node.js Simple Server JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started last week learning JavaScript and Node.js. Before that I developed with Java WebObjects and VB.NET. I just want to learn it for my self.

My brain is hurting after this week because of closures and other JavaScript stuff.

And now the question. To create a simple Node server I always found some code like this.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

Is there any difference if I would write the code like this?

```
var http = require("http");


var serverCallback = function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}

var server = http.createServer(serverCallback);
server.listen(3000);
```

For me this is more readable. But I'm not really sure that its exact the same.

Comment: You meant "closures"?

Comment: Why should you do `var serverCallback = function(` and why not just  `function serverCallback(`? ;)

Comment: there are usually 100s of callback in an web app, they are almost no shared and I never separate a callback if it is not shared.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in functionality. Use whatever style you like.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference in this case how the variables are assigned, found this yesterday in HN
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7672131